# Is there a way to create an element and bind an event to it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Is there a way I could use JavaScript to create an element, that when a user writes in it (oninput) I could display the text in the console? For example, it would be something like this:

```
<textarea oninput="print(this);"></textarea>
<script>
function print(e) {
  console.log(e.value);
}
</script>
```

My function is a little bit more complex but you get the idea. What I want is to create the `<textarea>` element using JavaScript and then set an `input` event on it and pass it the `this` object.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? [Creating the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)? [Binding an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should explain the procedure pretty clearly:

```js
// Selects an existing element in the DOM
const theParentElement = document.getElementById("container");

// Makes our new element
const newTextArea = document.createElement("textarea");

// Adds the new element to the DOM
theParentElement.appendChild(newTextArea);

// Calls printText when the textarea receives key input (or actually, ANY input)
newTextArea.addEventListener("input", printText);

// The listener gets a reference to the triggering event. Let's call it `event`
function printText(event){
  
  // The event's `target` property holds the element where the event happened
  const localReferenceToTheTextArea = event.target;

  // The text of a textarea  element lives in its `value` property
  const text = localReferenceToTheTextArea.value;

  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Not only “receives key input”, but rather “is changed using any input method” (drag-drop, paste, etc. included). This still doesn’t pass a “this”; you can just replace `event.target` by `this`, though.

Comment: Honestly, I do believe this way is a bit too complicated. The way the @SebastianSimon shows it in the question is a lot simpler.

Comment: @Rojo I have no idea what you mean by _“The way SebastianSimon shows it in the question is a lot simpler”_. `someContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("textarea")).addEventListener("input", function(){ printText(this); });` with the pre-defined function `printText` from the OP ([renamed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) `print`) or something related is the correct way.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I mean the way he edited your `print () {}` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
```

Then bind an event listener to your newly created element:

```
textarea.addEventListener("input", function () { /*Do the thing*/ });
```

That way, the event listener would always be binded to the element you've created.

I hope this helps you in some way. :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly you can do something like this

```
var myTextarea = document.createElement("textarea")
myTextarea.setAttribute("oninput", "print(this);")
// we get something like this => <textarea oninput="print(this);"></textarea>

document.body.appendChild( myTextarea )
console.log(myTextarea)
```

or you can use javascript EventListener

```
var myTextarea = document.createElement("textarea")
/* add the textarea to the body */
document.body.appendChild( myTextarea )
/* when we can use EventListener */
myTextarea.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
    /* do something with value*/
    console.log( myTextarea.vlaue )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="area"></textarea>

<script>
  const textArea = document.getElementById("area"); // Defines `textArea`
  textArea.addEventListener("input", e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well first, you put set a variable to the element you want to create. In your case, `<textarea>`

```
var textareaElement = document.createElement("textarea");
```

Then, set the `oninput` like this:

```
textareaElement.setAttribute("oninput", "print(this)");
```

Lastly, add the element to the `body`:

```
document.body.appendChild(textareaElement);
```

Put together:

```js
function print(e) {
  console.log(e.value);
}

var textareaElement = document.createElement("textarea");
textareaElement.setAttribute("oninput", "print(this)");
document.body.appendChild(textareaElement);
```